# Task 'rustc' has overflowed its stack

Tags: stack-overflow, rust

Chat server which fails to compile:

```
use std::io::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::io::{Acceptor, Listener};

enum StreamOrSlice {
     Strm(TcpStream),
     Slc(uint, [u8, ..1024])
}

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1", 5555);

    // bind the listener to the specified address
    let mut acceptor = listener.listen();

    let (tx, rx) = channel();

    spawn(proc() {
        let mut streams: Vec<TcpStream> = Vec::new();
        loop {
            let rxd: StreamOrSlice = rx.recv();
            match rxd {
                Strm(stream) => {
                    streams.push(stream);
                }
                Slc(len, buf) => {
                    for stream in streams.iter_mut() {
                        let _ = stream.write(buf.slice(0, len));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // accept connections and process them, spawning a new tasks for each one
    for stream in acceptor.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Err(e) => { /* connection failed */ }
            Ok(mut stream) => {
                // connection succeeded
                tx.send(Strm(stream.clone()));
                let tx2 = tx.clone();
                spawn(proc() {
                    let mut buf: [u8, ..1024] = [0, ..1024];
                    loop {
                        let len = stream.read(buf);
                        tx2.send(Slc(len.unwrap(), buf));
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
   Compiling chat v0.1.0 (file:///home/chris/rust/chat)
task 'rustc' has overflowed its stack
Could not compile `chat`.
```

Is this fixable in code, or is it a compiler bug?

Note: @Levans thanks for your help this evening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler has crashed.  You are not even writing your own macros.  This is 100% a compiler bug.  Report it.

Comment: Running it in gdb shows that it’s two-part recursion, jumping back and forth between `rustc::middle::trans::_match::compile_submatch` and `rustc::middle::trans::_match::compile_submatch_continue`. Removing the match inside the loop in the spawned proc does fix it… must dig further to produce a minimal test case.

Comment: OK, that’s a fascinating bug. It’s simply the matching against `[u8, ..1024]`. I filed it as https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/17877

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Could you suggest an approach for working around this bug, until it is fixed?

Comment: @chrisdew: if you switch from `[u8, ..1024]` to `Vec<u8>` it will be fixed. The relevant new parts: `let mut buf = Vec::from_elem(1024, 0);`, `stream.read(buf.as_mut_slice())`, `Slc(len.unwrap(), buf.clone())`. Better still, once you’re doing that, drop the `uint` part of `Slc` and change to `tx2.send(Slc(buf.slice_to(len.unwrap()).to_vec()`.